# How to add an image to a NSOutlineView

Tags: swift, nsoutlineview

I'm trying to add an image to a cell in a NSOutlineView :

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {
    df.locale = Locale.current
    df.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("YYYY-MM-dd")
    if ( df.locale.identifier == "fr_FR" ) {df.dateFormat="dd-MM-YYYY"}

    if ( myView == 0 ) {
        if let c = item as? Competition {
            if tableColumn?.identifier == "col1" {
                if let view = outlineView.make(withIdentifier: "column1", owner: self) as? NSTableCellView{
                    if let viewTextField = view.textField{
                        viewTextField.stringValue = df.string(from: c.date)
                    }

                    view.imageView?.image = NSImage(named: "NSSlideshowTemplate")

                    return view;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

But it's not working.
I have no problem with a NSTableView ..

Any idea why ?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: Are you using a `NSTableCellView` with text field and image view (there is one only with text field). By the way: **You** designed the UI, **you** know that cell and the identifier exists and that there is a text field and an image view, so you can (should) forced unwrap the optionals. If the app crashes, it will reveal a design error (which is a benefit).

Comment: it's working, thanks for the tip !!!
I wasn't using the right type of NSTableCellView